# Worklight deployed app fails to run with "Error 404: SRVE0190E: File not found: /"

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio, worklight-server

I have installed Eclipse 4.2.2 and Worklight 6.0.0.  When I create, build all and deploy, and I paste the URL found in the console, (http://*my.ip.address*:10080/SimpleProject/) it fails with **"Error 404: SRVE0190E: File not found: /"**.  This is true for both the Project and the MobileBrowserSimulator.

Console output:

```
[AUDIT   ] CWWKE0001I: The server worklight has been launched.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0058I: Monitoring dropins for applications. 
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://9.80.52.215:10080/SimpleProject/
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application SimpleProject started in 9.837 seconds.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://9.80.52.215:10080/_MobileBrowserSimulator/
```

Environment:
Windows 7 64 bit.
Eclipse 4.2.2 build 20130225-0426
Worklight 6.0.0.20130926-1933

**Found the answer:** The cause was an incomplete URL. I found I was able to start the Worklight Console from the context menu of the project "Start Worklight Console". I was then able to start the application from the running console.

Investigating the URLs, I found that the URL in the console log is not sufficient. You must append /console/ to the URL:

```
http:/9.80.52.215:10080/SimpleProject/console/
http:/<my.ip.address>/<myproject>/console
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to go to http://my.ip.address:10080/SimpleProject/console (notice I added /console) to get to the Worklight Console for that project.

Answer (score 0):

Also, the issue with the url in the console log missing "/console" is a defect and will be addressed in a future release.